# Bing API not giving outputs of subdomains in Burp Suite (Following through Blackhat Python)

Tags: java, python, multithreading, bing-api, burp

I have linked bhp_bing.py as an extension in Burp Suite. But My Burp Suite is not giving outputs of the target site's subdomains. 
[supposed result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w79ZR.png)

But mine stops at "performing bing search*****"
and I checked the error log and it shows this:

**java.lang.RuntimeException: Extensions should not make HTTP requests in the swing event dispatch thread**

Here is the source code for bhp_bing.py:

https://github.com/walchko/Black-Hat-Python/blob/master/BHP-Code/Chapter6/bhp_bing.py

Anyone could help me? Really appreciated:)

Answer (score 0):

Burp is blocking the self._callbacks.makeHttpRequest() call because it's executing in the Swing (user-interface) thread. If Burp allowed this, the entire UI would lock up briefly while the HTTP request was sent. To fix it, you need to spawn a new thread in which to execute the bing_query function.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have figured it out. Just out of curiosity, why does the code works in the book? It was written in 2014. Did Burp allow self._callbacks.makeHttpRequest() call before?

Comment: Yeah, Burp probably used to allow such calls. It's hard to enable powerful extensions without letting them hurt the user experience. If you've got working code, could you submit it in a pull request to help out other people working through the book?